# Convert Vector in Table in R

Tags: r

I am new to **R**. We are using dataset of Trip Advisor for getting values like "Value", "OverAll", "Rooms" etc. in each designated Array.
The result is as follows

```
Value <- as.numeric(c("4","3","5","2.5"))

Overall <- as.numeric(c("4","4.5","2","3"))

Rooms <- as.numeric(c("3","4","2","2"))
```

I want to get values in Table like.

```
Value    4    3     5     2.5

Overall    4    4.5    2    3

Rooms    3    4     2     2
```

I tried to convert it into 2D Array as well as `table(Value,Overall,Rooms)`. Converting to array led to an error, and `table()` is not changing it into my required format. Please guide where I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rbind`

```
rbind(Value = c("4","3","5","2.5"),
      Overall = c("4","4.5","2","3"),
      Rooms = c("3","4","2","2"))

        [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4] 
Value   "4"  "3"   "5"  "2.5"
Overall "4"  "4.5" "2"  "3"  
Rooms   "3"  "4"   "2"  "2"
```

Since you manipulates score here (TripAdvisor notes) , it is better to convert them to numeric, before creating the matrix:

```
rbind(Value = as.numeric(c("4","3","5","2.5")),
      Overall = as.numeric(c("4","4.5","2","3")),
      Rooms =as.numeric( c("3","4","2","2")))

       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
Value      4  3.0    5  2.5
Overall    4  4.5    2  3.0
Rooms      3  4.0    2  2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want data frame:

```
data.frame(Value=Value,Overall=Overall,Rooms=Rooms)
```

Or matrix:

```
 rbind(Value=Value,Overall=Overall,Rooms=Rooms)
```

Note that as you have made your data by

```
Value <- c("4","3","5","2.5")
Overall <- c("4","4.5","2","3")
Rooms <- c("3","4","2","2")
```

instead of

```
Value <- c(4,3,5,2.5)
Overall <- c(4,4.5,2,3)
Rooms <- c(3,4,2,2)
```

you get characters instead of numbers. Now if you do some modelling, the values "4", "3" etc. are taken as factors (see `?factors`), so you cannot have value such as 3.5, which I think you would like to have as you also have 2.5 etc.

The function `table` is used for tables of counts and things like that:

```
table(c("a","b","a","d","abc","b","b"))
  a abc   b   d 
  2   1   3   1
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you to collect the JSON data-set, then you can easily parse them, as R is very strong for extracting data from JSON.
You may visit: https://www.rstudio.com/online-learning/

Comment: As this is a programming community it would be very helpful for you to post some example code with your answer.